# Laravel: `php artisan app:name MyApp` caused an exception

Tags: laravel, exception

I've made a clean Laravel installation, then I've run

```
php artisan app:name MyApp
```

and now I get the following error in both command line and the browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 
'Class MyApp\Http\Kernel does not exist' in 
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:736
```

I can't change the name back too because of the error. 
It seems that namespace wasn't changed but the app expected it to change which means that artisan app:name caused this bug.

How do I fix this installation?

How to prevent this error from happening in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your paths in `bootstrap/app.php`  are correct, and try running the command `composer dump-autoload` .

If it still does not work, try a global search & replace to change the `MyApp` namespace back to `App`.

Comment: Thanks Drown. Global search and replace helped. I'm just wondering why the error occured in the first place?